# Nested queries to different databases

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm trying to use INFORMATION_SCHEMA, because I think it will help a lot on what i want to do. I tried to find the right query, but none of them worked. The common thing in all queries was that I used nested queries on different databases. The last one I used was this one below.

```
SELECT table_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE column_name='field1'
AND table_schema='database1'
AND (SELECT * FROM database1.table_name WHERE field1 > somevalue ) IS 
NOT NULL
```

But this returned error

> #1146 - Table 'database1.table_name' doesn't exist.

Is this because i'm using two nested queries each to a different database? Is there a way I can make this work?

What I want to do is a list of the table names of a database which have field1 in their field list and at least one of the values of field1 is greater than *somevalue*.

I use MySQL v5.5

Comment: There's no restriction on accessing different databases in the same query, nested or otherwise. Are you sure the table `table_name` really exists in the database `database1`? Also, your nested query won't work if the subquery returns multiple rows or columns.

Comment: I suspect what you really need is dynamic SQL. If you're trying to scan all the tables in `information_schema.columns`, it doesn't make sense to hard-code the table name in the subquery.

Comment: `database1` doesn't have any table named `table_name`. I use `database1.table_name` so that it references the values of `table_name` right after `SELECT`. Do I explain myself? I hope I'm not confusing you.

Comment: Table and column names in queries are not variables that get substituted, they're treated literally. That's why you need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot! I've no idea of dynamic SQL, but I'll find my way :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd advice you to use a join other than a nested query

Comment: That won't solve the problem if the table he's joining with doesn't exist.